# Can I trigger a Jenkins job using a Maven dependency?

Tags: maven, triggers, jenkins, dependencies, pom.xml

I have multiple Jenkins Jobs built using Maven:

```
Job 1: Builds WebApp and deploys war to artifactory
Job 2: Builds Core and deploys jar to artifactory
```

WebApp has a dependency on Core.

Is it possible for Jenkins to parse the POM, see that WebApp has this dependency on Core and thus triggers Job 2 before building WebApp?  This would ensure WebApp uses an up-to-date, latest Core.jar

I can achieve this mechanism via the Jenkins Parameterized Trigger plugin's Pre-Steps feature but I would ideally like to handle this from the POM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is.

1. you need to set up the jobs as Maven Job

[image]

2. In Job A select the checkbox: Build whenever a snapshot dependency is build.

[image]

Apparently this only works, if the dependency is a snapshot dependency.

Comment: Doesn't this only trigger it's job based on when another dependency is built?  So using my example, Job 1 would be triggered when Job 2 has been built.  This is not what I want.

I want Job 1 to trigger Job 2 when Job 1 is started because it is aware it has a dependency on a project that is built in Job 2.

Comment: Yes that is correct. But what is the problem with doing it the other way around? Having Job1 being triggered whenever Job2 sees any changes would in my opinion be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use the [Maven Dependency Update trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Dependency+Update+trigger) plugin. This is if you use a freestyle job instead of a Maven job type.

Comment: Does this also trigger the job when non-snapshot dependencies have been built?

Comment: Did you read the plugin page? "This plugin will check if any SNAPSHOT dependencies (or optionally plugins SNAPSHOT) have been updated during your project's dependencies resolution and trigger a build."

Comment: Yes I have read it, but I was curious if it was capable of doing more than this. We are currently going away from using snapshots, but these plugins don't seem to support this.

Comment: If you need more control over triggering jobs, look at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ScriptTrigger+Plugin

Comment: Ok, but this ScriptTrigger plugin does not take any advantage of the POM, does it?

Comment: That is up to you to do. You might have more luck sending an email to the Jenkins user list or in irc.